# Heroku composer install: Host key verification failed

Tags: php, heroku, composer-php, rsa, bitbucket

I am trying to deploy my PHP project on Herkoku trough the `git push` command. This is going fine until composer fails to install my private packages stored in private repositories at Bitbucket. The message returned is:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: -----> PHP app detected
remote: -----> Bootstrapping...
remote: -----> Installing platform packages...
remote:        - php (7.0.6)
remote:        - ext-exif (bundled with php)
remote:        - ext-gd (bundled with php)
remote:        - ext-mbstring (bundled with php)
remote:        - apache (2.4.20)
remote:        - nginx (1.8.1)
remote: -----> Installing dependencies...
remote:        Composer version 1.1.1 2016-05-17 12:25:44
remote:        Loading composer repositories with package information
remote:        Installing dependencies from lock file
remote:          - Installing doctrine/lexer (dev-master 83893c5)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:
remote:          - Installing doctrine/annotations (dev-master f25c8aa)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:
remote:          - Installing doctrine/cache (dev-master e0ef9e9)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:
remote:          - Installing doctrine/collections (dev-master 866e100)
remote:            Downloading: 100%
remote:
remote:          - Installing private-repo/private-repo (dev-master cff3e2d)
remote:            Cloning cff3e2d83977df680e724b8857f18ebea85af420
remote:
remote:          [RuntimeException]
remote:          Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout 'git@bitbucket.org:private-repo/private-repo.git' '/tmp/build_83b3c2f9665a4335124a98bf13b0d85b/vendor/private-repo/private-repo' && cd '/tmp/build_83b3c2f9665a4335124a98bf13b0d85b/vendor/private-repo/private-repo' && git remote add composer 'git@bitbucket.org:private-repo/private-repo.git' && git fetch composer
remote:          Cloning into '/tmp/build_83b3c2f9665a4335124a98bf13b0d85b/vendor/private-repo/private-repo'...

remote:          Host key verification failed.
remote:          fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
remote:          Please make sure you have the correct access rights
remote:          and the repository exists.

remote:
remote:        install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--op
timize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
remote:
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to xxx.
```

I already uploaded my rsa-key i normally use authenticating with Bitbucket onto my Heroku account.

**Does somebody know how to let Heroku authenticate with my Bitbucket repositories?**

Comment: Did you search with Google for this problem? What about the Heroku documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working. Now using http basic authentication to connect Heroku with Bitbucket. Followed these steps:

Converted the repository urls my package.json (containing my private packages) 
from: `git@bitbucket.org:private-repo/private-repo.git`
to:

`https://username@bitbucket.org/private-repo/private-repo.git`

Then added the following config to my composer.json:

```
"config": {
    "bitbucket-oauth": {
        "bitbucket.org": {
            "consumer-key": "Bitbucket username",
            "consumer-secret": "Bitbucket password"
        }
    }
}
```

Its not recommended to store your password in a plain-text file but unfortunately Bitbucket does not give us a choice